# PHP - Notice: Undefined variable happening twice

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting the following two errors when loading my page:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: realtor in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www\cglst\images\addform.php on line 255
```

and

```
Notice: Undefined variable: phone in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www\cglst\images\addform.php on line 256
```

I do define both those variables, though, so I don't understand why I'm getting these errors. Here is my code:

```
function addListing() {//if data was provided, insert it into database and confirm
    //this will allow everything to be sanitized properly
    require_once "sanitize.php";
    $submitted = false;

    //Checking if values were passed
    if (isset($_POST['area']) &&
        isset($_POST['price']) &&
        isset($_POST['address']) &&
        isset($_POST['bedrooms']) &&
        isset($_POST['fullbath']) &&
        isset($_POST['halfbath']) &&
        isset($_POST['sqft']))
        //if passed, sanitize and set variables accordingly
        {
            $area = sanitizeOne(get_post('area'), 'plain');
            $price = sanitizeOne(get_post('price'), 'int');
            $address = sanitizeOne(get_post('address'), 'plain');
            $bedrooms = sanitizeOne(get_post('bedrooms'), 'int');
            $fullbath = sanitizeOne(get_post('fullbath'), 'int');
            $halfbath = sanitizeOne(get_post('halfbath'), 'int');
            $sqft = sanitizeOne(get_post('sqft'), 'int');
            $submitted = true;
        }

    //optional fields
    if (isset($_POST['remarks']))
        {
            $remarks = sanitizeOne(get_post('remarks'), 'plain');
        }
    else
        {$remarks = ' ';}

    if (isset($_POST['realtor']))
        {
            $remarks = sanitizeOne(get_post('realtor'), 'plain');
        }
    else
        {$realtor = "Anne-Marie Pelletier";}

    if (isset($_POST['phone']))
        {
            $remarks = sanitizeOne(get_post('phone'), 'plain');
        }
    else
        {$phone = "201.710.5500";}

    if ($submitted) {
        $query = 'PREPARE statement FROM "INSERT INTO bix(area, price, address, bedrooms, 
                fullbath, halfbath, sqft, remarks, realtor, phone) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"';
        mysql_query($query);
        $query = 'SET 
                    @area = "' . $area . '"' .
                    '@price = "' . $price . '"' .
                    '@address = "' . $address . '"' .
                    '@bedrooms = "' . $bedrooms . '"' .
                    '@fullbath = "' . $fullbath . '"' .
                    '@halfbath = "' . $halfbath . '"' .
                    '@sqft = "' . $sqft . '"' .
                    '@remarks = "' . $remarks . '"' .
                    '@realtor = "' . $realtor . '"' . //line 255
                    '@phone = "' . $phone . '"'; //line 256
        mysql_query($query);
        $query = 'EXECUTE statement USING @area,@price,@address,@bedrooms,@fullbath,@halfbath,@sqft,@remarks,@realtor,@phone';
        mysql_query($query);
        $query = 'DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement';
        mysql_query($query);
        return true;
    }
}
function get_post($var)
{
    return mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$var]);
}
```

This is simply adding an entry to a database if it was submitted (the page submits a form to itsself to do this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here, a cut'n'paste error;

```
if (isset($_POST['realtor']))
{
    $remarks = sanitizeOne(get_post('realtor'), 'plain');
}
else
    {$realtor = "Anne-Marie Pelletier";}
```

If realtor is set as a post parameter, you assign the post variable's value to *`$remarks`* instead of to *`$realtor`*.

*`$phone`*  has the exact same problem.

Comment: ok new problem: It's adding entries to my database, but every field is null somehow...

Comment: Your `SET` query does not have commas separating the parameters and I'm pretty sure the quotes need to be `'`, not `"` for the strings. Try echoing it and see if it runs as is in PhpMyAdmin. Either way, you're not checking any return values, that would make it much easier to diagnose.

Comment: I didn't think of echoing the statements and trying them out. That helped me solve all my problems. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the phone value was passed you are setting the remarks variable to the phone content, if its not set you are setting the fixed phone

change:

```
    if (isset($_POST['phone']))
    {
        $remarks = sanitizeOne(get_post('phone'), 'plain');
    }
else
    {$phone = "201.710.5500";}
```

to

```
    if (isset($_POST['phone']))
    {
        $phone = sanitizeOne(get_post('phone'), 'plain');
    }
else
    {$phone = "201.710.5500";}
```

Same for the realtor

To debug the all-null problem, try to record a record without realtor or phone i.e. using the defaults in code. if you get those two values stored, then the problem is in santizeOne, post the code to that for us to help. If its not try to capture the output of all the first to queries and post it.

Answer (score 0):

You are never assigning anything to $realtor or $phone.

```
if (isset($_POST['realtor']))
        {
            $remarks = sanitizeOne(get_post('realtor'), 'plain');
        }
```

you probably mean to use `$realtor = sanitizeOne(get_post('realtor'), 'plain');`

same for $phone.